# Como puedo hacer una peticion ajax con diferentes id?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Tengo 3 elementos de tipo input numero_de_pacu, numero_de_pacu2, numero_de_pacu3, como podria agregar los 3 a la variable url cadena para poder interactuar con un controlador escrito en python

```
function semaforico() {

var pedido = document.getElementById("numero_de_pacu").value;
var pedido2 = document.getElementById("numero_de_pacu2").value;
var pedido3 = document.getElementById("numero_de_pacu3").value;
                
var urlcadena = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/pedido-cocido/semaforico' + '?pedido=' +
                    pedido;
$.ajax({
    url: urlcadena,
    success: function (respuesta) {
        var strings = JSON.stringify(respuesta);
        window.respuesta = strings;                  
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
});
```

}

Este es el controlador escrito en python el cual hace una consulta por orm que obtiene el numero de cantidad disponible de un producto en especifico, posteriormente retorna un json para poder procesar datos con javascript y ajax, actualmente solo funciona para un producto pero quisiera poder ingresar los demas productos.

```
@http.route(['/pedido-cocido/semaforico'], auth="public", type="http")
def semaforico(self, **post):

    pedido = post.get('pedido') or None
    callback = post.get('callback')     
    if callback:
        return "HOLA Esta es la respuesta del SEMAFORICO 1"
    else:
        
        product_id = request.env['product.template'].sudo().search([('id', '=', 12)],limit=1)
        disponible = int(product_id.qty_available) - int(pedido)

        vals = {
            'product_disponible':disponible,
        }
        return json.dumps(vals)
```

Gracias a todos por su tiempo!

Comment: Puedes ponerlo todo en la URL, pero en python tendrás que separarlo o haces peticiones por separado

Comment: En jQuery Ajax admite un parámetro `data` en el cual puedes pasar un objeto que identifique cada valor, por ejemplo: `var toPost= {alpha:pedido, beta:pedido2, gamma:pedido3};` si pasas esto en Ajax: `data: toPost,` podrás identificar en el servidor cada valor mediante las claves `alpha, beta, gamma` recuperándolos del post. En ese caso no tienes que pasar valores en la URL.